# how to have nested child route in angularjs 2 using ID

Tags: javascript, angular

My sample [Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/Od0Bv2/)

i"m new in angularjs 2

how to show twitter names for corresponding names using routes in same page using second `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

tried routing for child one (sample one not for this app)

`children: [{path: 'child-one', component: ApplicationSecondComponent},`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have default child route, so use next route configuration:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ContactsListComponent, children: [{
      path: '',
      component: ContactsDetailComponent
    }, { 
      path: 'contact/:id',
      component: ContactsDetailComponent,

      resolve: {
        contact: 'contact'
      }
    }] 
  }
];
```

So you should control `contact` empty state using `*nfIf` directive also in your details component

```
<div *ngIf="contact">
  <h2>{{contact.name}}</h2>

  <dl>
    <dt>Twitter</dt>
    <dd>{{contact.twitter}}</dd>
  </dl>

  <p><a routerLink="/">Back to list</a></p>
</div>
```

And additional routing outlete inside list template

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts | async">
    <a [routerLink]="['contact', contact.id]">{{contact.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Also be careful - you need to move your contact resolve login into details component as you need to react to url params chages. This code will works only one:

```
this.contact = this.route.snapshot.data['contact'];
```

Please review updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ZgbBKaF58brxILueKkxv?p=preview

Comment: hi thank you for your answer but the plunker you provide was not getting the values when i click the values

Comment: When you select list item it shows details below this list. Yes? But I said before - it should be resolved redesigned to use `.subscribe` in `ActivatedRoute`, because your snapshot will store only first selection

Comment: can you explain in plunker ?

Comment: OK. After clicking item in list your detail will be rendered below. The first problem here - tour detail component takes `contact` data using: `this.contact = this.route.snapshot.data['contact'];`. The problem that having child route your snapshot will remain not changed untill root route do not change. So here you need to add `this.route.params.subscribe...` to read route changes and resolve contact.

Comment: thank a lot can you provide me a plunker example so that i can mark this as answer

Comment: Try this solution. Does it solve your problem? https://plnkr.co/edit/ZgbBKaF58brxILueKkxv?p=preview